# bootstrap columns on same row on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this row using horizontal form to show the label on the left side. On Mobile i want the label to occupy one row, and I want the 3 textboxes to remain on the same row, how to acheive this? They will stack on top of each other still

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="dobDay" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-form-label">Date Of Birth</label>
                                
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobDay" placeholder="DD">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobMonth" placeholder="MM">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobYear" placeholder="AAAA">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the [equal-width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#equal-width) class `.col`:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="dobDay" class="col-12 col-md col-form-label" />
    <div class="col">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

You set `col-12` on Date of Birth label so that it would occupy a row for extra small devices (less than 576px). Since other 3 columns are set with `col`, they will take up equal width on their own row. That would give you the `col-sm-4` effect.

On medium devices and up, the Date of Birth label, with `col-md`, will join the `equal-width` group as well. That would give you the `col-md-3` effect.

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/yr5gp6kq/8/

Answer (score 0):

That stacking was because you didn't mention breakpoints for `xs` devices.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="dobDay" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-form-label">Date Of Birth</label>
            
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobDay" placeholder="DD">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobMonth" placeholder="MM">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dobYear" placeholder="AAAA">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```